# How do I import An image with transparancy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

So im trying to render my minecraft 3d skin but the hat it not being transparant
[image: What the import looks like]
[image: The result]

Comment: @Leander Is it still a duplicate, when today we have Principled BSDF with a dedicated Alpha input?

Comment: The question is, the answer is not.

Answer (score 1):

This has a rather simple solution:

You need to connect your image Alpha (transparency) channel.
In your material, set up nodes like this and it will work.
In *Eevee* you also need to enable *Alpha Blend*.

*Cycles render Engine.*
[image]

*Eevee render engine. Remember to enable Alpha Blend.*
[image]

Comment: OMG THANK YOUUUUU

Comment: Happy to help :). You can now mark the answer as accepted (the green checkmark). Cheers.