# remove artifacts from transparent image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, artifacts

I'm trying to render an image using cycles and my rendered image has these background artifacts that look like lines. These lines match up with the extent of the picture. I made both images (the one for color and the one for height) have transparent backgrounds in Photoshop before bringing them into blender. How do I get rid of these lines? I should note that if I remove the plane from under the two canyon images, their original extents are visible after rendering.

[image]

Comment: here are the nodes [link](https://imgur.com/a/aHXgJHP)

Comment: if you use images with transparency you should use the Image Texture "Alpha" output socket and use it as a factor between the image and a Transparent node, why don't you?

Comment: Hello :). You need to connect your alpha channel. [Here's my answer to a similar question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159114/78972)